# Имеются два проекта, второй не работает как нужно, когда запущен из первого, но работает, когда запущен самостоятельно

Tags: c#, .net

Имеются два проекта(transmitter и receiver) C# Winodws forms .Net Framework 4.6, один из них по щелчку кнопки пишет в файл, а другой по таймеру читает из этого файла.
Имеется функция в проекте transmitter

```
 if(!Process.GetProcessesByName("receiver").Any())
 Process.Start(@"C:\Users\имяпользователя\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\receiver\receiver\bin\Debug\receiver.exe");
```

которая открывает receiver, но в нем тогда не работает таймер, или текст не читается - в общем, проблема.
Но если receiver запустить ручками из той же Debug папки, то он взаимодействует с файлом и спокойной читает из него текст, в том числе текст, который туда пишет transmitter.

В чем соль?

[Проекты ресивер и трансмиттер на Яндекс Диске](https://yadi.sk/d/E1qvm7UD3JbuZf%22%D0%A1%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Код формы проекта transmitter

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace transmitter
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Receiver_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamWriter fileWrite = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\имяпользователя\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\receiver\receiver\bin\Debug\file.txt");
            fileWrite.Write(textBox_input.Text);
            fileWrite.Close();
        }

        catch
        {
            Thread.Sleep(300);
            StreamWriter fileWrite = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Имяпользователя\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\receiver\receiver\bin\Debug\file.txt");
            fileWrite.Write(textBox_input.Text);
            fileWrite.Close();
        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName("receiver").Any())
        {
             Process[] ps1 = Process.GetProcessesByName("receiver");
             ps1[0].CloseMainWindow();
        }
    }

    private void textBox_input_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Label_KeyDown.Text = Convert.ToString(e.KeyValue);
    }

    private void textBox_input_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Label_KeyUp.Text = Convert.ToString(e.KeyValue);
    }

    private void textBox_input_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        Label_KeyPress.Text = Convert.ToString((int)e.KeyChar);
    }

    private void button_OpenReceiver_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Process.GetProcessesByName("receiver").Any())
        Process.Start(@"C:\Users\имяпользователя\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\receiver\receiver\bin\Debug\receiver.exe");
    }

    private void button_Transmitter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox_Transmitter.Lines = textBox_input.Text.Split(' ', ',',',');
    }
}
```

}

Код формы проекта receiver

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


   using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;

    namespace receiver

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                StreamReader fileRead = new StreamReader(@"File.txt");
                textBox1.Text = fileRead.ReadToEnd();
                fileRead.Close();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, сократите код проектов до минимального самовоспроизводимого примера и приведите его прямо в теле вопроса.

Comment: Нужно ли прилагать код designer или только самой Form1.cs ?

Comment: Правку совершил. Если сократить до примера- то я его первоначально и привел - Process.Start().. Ибо именно с результатом его деятельности у меня проблема.

Comment: Проблема, скорее всего, в указании неполного имени файла `File.txt`. Текущий каталог вовсе не обязан совпадать с каталогом, в котором лежит программа.

Comment: @vlaD файл file.txt находится по месту жительства - в папке с дебагом.  Или же вы думаете, что раз запускается второй процесс через первый, то и файл ищется вторым процессом, в папке первого? Проверю. Upd: Черт, вы были правы! И почему такое происходит? ведь файл со второй программой находится вместе с файлом тхт. Что за самодурство и изменение работы второй программы, смотря, откуда она запущена? Может есть какие то дополнительные неявные способы задать путь? , Типа подняться на несколько директорий вверх?

Comment: @elislavkat: Я знаю, что ищется в **текущем** каталоге. Который не обязательно совпадает с каталогом, в котором лежит программа.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема оказалась в том, что в проекте receiver файл.тхт искался по пути - @file.txt без полного пути, и видимо, раз ресивер запускался из папки трансмиттера, то файл и искался по пути @file.txt в папке трансмиттера.. жуть

Comment: Это не жуть, так было всегда. Вы бы почитали документацию :) Нужно всегда задавать полный путь. Иначе файл ищется в [текущем каталоге](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx).